# Android networking

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I'm new to android development I'm writing an application that will talk to a server over TCP/IP I was planning to use the java.net.Socket package but then I've found that there is a android.net.LocalSocket also.
Does anyone know the difference between these or have a suggestion when to use which one of these.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[java.net.Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) is for creating TCP/IP sockets.

[android.net.LocalSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html) is for creating [unix domain sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) in the abstract namespace or on the filesystem. These are used for inter process communication.

You need to use java.net.Socket as you say you need TCP/IP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider checking the API references first?  Here's the definition for [java.net.Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) and [android.net.LocalSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html).  The latter is described as, "*Creates a (non-server) socket in the UNIX-domain namespace. The interface here is not entirely unlike that of java.net.Socket*"; the obvious difference is it has a single public constructor `LocalSocket()`.

Comment: Yes I read the API ,the "not entirely unlike"  made me a little bit confused. Why should I select one over the other. 
Any suggestion when to use which one of them?